# namespace myspace { int x } Now why `myspace::x=3;` gives error?

Tags: c++, namespaces

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
namespace myspace
{
    int x;
}

myspace::x=3; // This line is giving error.
int main()
{
    myspace::x=5;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
```

So why line `myspace::x=3;` giving error that C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations ?

Comment: The same situtation as `int x; x = 3; int main() {}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement

```
myspace::x=3;
```

isn't an initialization, it's a plain assignment. It's no different from the

```
myspace::x=5;
```

you have inside the `main` function.

Any statement that isn't a declaration or a definition can't be outside functions.

If you want to initialize the variable, do it at the definition:

```
namespace myspace
{
    int x = 3;
}
```

Comment: or https://godbolt.org/z/PYrjera5T

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know it's not platform to talk this but I also don't see any other option to contact with you. I am in final year of graduation. So we have to some research project . Can you please give  an idea to do research project in C++

Answer (score 3):

You provided a definition upon first declaring the variable. And as others noted `myspace::x=3;` constitutes an assignment expression at namespace scope, which is not allowed.

If you want to declare the variable without defining it, you need to be explicit and specify it's an `extern` declaration.

```
namespace myspace
{
    extern int x;
}
```

The definition would still need the type specifier (as all definitions do), but it will look somewhat like what you imagined

```
int myspace::x = 3;
```

While all of this is fine and dandy, global variables (the mutable, run-time external kind)  are a code smell. So best not to get in the habit of using them.